# JSP page as a links in tabs method of jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui

I am using the tabs method of jQuery UI to navigate in different jsp pages. When I click the tab, it's not navigating to another page instead it's loading in the same page which I would like to avoid. I am new to jQuery technology. Please help how to navigate to another jsp page using tabs of jQuery UI.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="tabs">  
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="ReportGeneration.jsp">Report Creation</a></li>   
            <li><a href="Index.jsp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="report.jsp">Request Report</a></li>  
            <li><a href="Upload.jsp">File Upload</a></li> 
            <li><a href="LoginRequest.jsp">Login Request</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use tabs for this?   Sounds like you are describing a menu.

Comment: Yes. I have to use tabs to redirect to another page. Is that possible?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. The whole point of the jQuery UI `.tabs()` is to stay on the same page. If all your links are to other pages, you don't need to use tabs, just a CSS menu.